# Return two types that derive from the same abstract class

Tags: c#, linq

I have an abstract class, let's call it Fruit.

There are two classes that derive from Fruit, let's call them Apple and Pear.

I have a function that needs to return both apples and pears by, let's say, their expiry date.

It looks something like this:

```
public Fruit[] GetFruitByDate(string date){
Apple[] apples=/*Linq result*/;
Pear[] pears=/*Linq result*/;
return apples+pears;//what do I do here?
}
```

How do I return the two results?

Thanks.

Comment: `return apples.Cast<Fruit>().Concat(pears.Cast<Fruit>()).ToArray();`

Comment: Yes, they have different members, it's just a bad example.

Comment: Are you sure you want those`[]` in a Linq world?

Comment: No, it's just an example I thought of on the spot( I know it's a bad one), I needed a way to be able to accomplish a return of two different children of the same class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
return apples.Cast<Fruit>().Concat(pears).ToArray();
```

Equally `Union` would work instead of `Concat`, but you probably don't need to worry about comparing the two types and de-duping them. I hear it's not good to compare apples to pears (oh wait, that's oranges).

Be sure to include this namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

When you call this method, if you need to get back to the subclass members, then you will need to do a safe cast on each item, or separate the types back out with by calling `.OfType<Apple>()` for example.

Comment: Yes, it does =)  To the downvoter: what do you want me to change?

Comment: I didn't down vote,  but `Union` does an implicit Distinct so you may lose duplicates.  `Concat` would be better. Also,  @master2080 while the properties and fields wouldnt be "lost", what you would have are references to `Fruit` so you'd only have direct access to its properties/fields without casting to the appropriate subclass `Apple` or `Pear` and to do that you'd have to know the specific item's type (probably by using an `is` check or an `as`+`!=null` check)

Answer (score 5):

If you have to keep casting things you're doing something wrong, or don't have a clear understanding of inheritance. putting a question with var and no real code after the = doesn't allow for a proper answer since Linq can return different types. I'll just assuming it returns and IEnnumarble of some sort.

```
public Fruit[] GetFruitByDate(string date){
List<Fruit> tResult = new List<Fruit>();
var apples=/*Linq result*/;
var pears=/*Linq result*/;
tResult.AddRange(apples);
tResult.AddRange(pears);
return tResult.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: the Linq does return different types, first result is an Apple[] type, and the second is a Pear[] type. They are both derived from Fruit. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Then the code example should work. I don't actually know of any Linq that returns an array but that's fine. Try the code above. It's cleaner and it doesn't constantly cast to base class.

Comment: Casting the Linq result with ToArray() returns an array, I just didn't have a better example than this, but needed an answer.

Comment: Okay, when working with Linq you want to avoid casting including ToArray(). Avoid casting until the very end. So you only have to do it once. If you can I would change the return for GetFruidByDate to return an IEnumarble<Fruit>  rather then an Array. It make the function more reusable in the future.

Comment: This was more of a general question about how to return two children of the same base class. I know the example is awful, but thanks for the explanation :)